# On utilizing the Leibniz rule of integration on a non compact interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I am following some slides that you can find [here](http://www.oxford-man.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/events/Patton_OMI_lec1_14_white.pdf).

At slide $\approx$  24 a problem arises, to find

$$\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min} \argmin_{\hat{y} } -\int_{-\infty}^{\hat{y}} (y -\hat{y}) f(y) \, dy + \int_{\hat{y}}^{\infty} (y -\hat{y}) f(y) \, dy  $$

the slides then state the Leibniz rule

$$
\frac \partial {\partial x} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,y)\,dy = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac \partial {\partial x} f(x,y)\,dy + f(b,y)\frac{\partial b}{\partial x} - f(a,y)\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}
$$

And follow with these calculations

\begin{align}
= {} & -\left( \int_{-\infty}^{\hat Y^*_{t+h,t}} (-1) f_{t+h\,\mid\,t} (y)\,dy +  (0) f_{t+h\,\mid\,t} \left( \hat Y^*_{t+h\,\mid\,t} \right)(1) - 0 \right) \\[10pt]
& + \left( \int_{\hat Y^*_{t+h\,\mid\,t}}^\infty (-1) f_{t+h\,\mid\,t} (y)\,dy + 0 - (0) f_{t+h\,\mid\,t} \left( \hat Y^*_{t+h\,\mid\,t} \right) (1) \right)
\end{align}

Apparently setting the derivative of $\infty$ equal to $0$? I was under the impression that the measure-theoretical version of Leibnitz rule was to be applied when we had a non-compact interval of integration.

Could somebody explain to me how to compute $\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial \hat{y}}$ and $\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial \hat{y}}$?

I add an other source I found searching for an answer that could give help an answerer:
http://web.uvic.ca/~dgiles/blog/median2.pdf

Comment: I found this: http://web.uvic.ca/~dgiles/blog/median2.pdf   that gives a proof in this manner but I still do not understand the justification in the case of a non compact interval of integration.